# Difference between Html:linkroute and simple link for edit functionality in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I wanted to ask what is the difference between Html:linkroute and simple link for edit functionality in Laravel. For example,

```
{!! Html:linkRoute("post.edit", "Edit", array("$post->id")) !!}
```

vs 
`<a href="/post/{{$post->id}}/edit">Edit</a>`

Comment: why don't just use <a href="{{ route('post.edit', $post) }}">Edit</a>

Comment: There is no major differences. Html:linkRoute is delivered by laravel collective. It is used to send a parameter to the route. 
general link recieve parameters in a simple way. that's it

Comment: Me again. To answer, practically nothing. Put both on the same page, check the page's source (via right click, view source) and compare the generated HTML. Do you have an actual "problem" that needs to be solved? These questions are starting to get off-topic for Stackoverflow; too many why, not enough how.

Comment: @TimLewis, hey dude glad you paid attention to my problem, yeah yeah I know it gets off-topic for Stackoverflow. Frankly, before deciding to ask here I certainly serve the net hoping to find some kind explanation and since I end up in nothing I decide to ask here or else I will be lost at all :)

Comment: if asking help with post laravel collective code, i guess only still using old laravel version can answer you, because this syntax is not documented in all new laravel version

Comment: @kenken9999, you mean I better abstain from using {!! Html:linkRoute("post.edit", "Edit", array("$post->id")) !!} in favour of <a href="/post/{{$post->id}}/edit">Edit</a>?

Comment: yes yes ;) at least for me, i don't understand what the source code behind `{!! Html:linkRoute("post.edit", "Edit", array("$post->id")) !!}`, so use `<a href="{{ route('post.edit', $post) }}">Edit</a>` instead

Comment: @TimLewis, Tim, the actual problem is I dunno which one to use yes they are basically the same but maybe there are nuances, that is, maybe one is better than the other. That's the actual reason I decided to create this question on the platform

Comment: Understandable, but the answer to that question is "Whichever **you** want to use " :P I, personally, use `href="{{ url("/") }}"` so I don't have to remember named routes, and I don't like the syntax of the `Html` facade. But, that's ground for being closed as "Primarily opinion-based", so be aware of that.

Comment: @TimLewis, ok ok Tim I got it, and certainly thank you for your explanation just perfect as always:)